# Run the code instead of bash in pycharm

Tags: python, bash, pycharm

I have a piece of code that is ran through terminal likes this under Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sh demo.sh
```

where inside `demo.sh`, a main python file is called as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
python main_test.py file.csv --header 0
```

Because I prefer to use **Pycharm** instead of terminal to avoid switching between python version which is cumbersome at some points, I want to write a runner that calls my main file `main_test.py` with the inputs `file.csv` and others if needed.

How can this be done?

Comment: Btw.: sh is not bash.

Comment: Look next `Run` button (on the right of the toolbar ), choose `edit configuration`, then specify the script to run and its parameters.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. I could not find precisely where in `edit configuration` we can specify the scripts and the associated parameters. Thanks for your suggestion in advance.

Comment: @WalR, your solution solved the problem. Thankls